# building an array object by pushing json

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, json

I have two objects as follows:

```
var id="one";
var arrobj = Array[2]
     0: Object
        name : "a"
        desc : "desc1"
     1: Object
        name : "b"
        desc : "desc2"
```

I am trying to build the object in the following format :

```
var secondobj = [{ "one" : [{ name:"a",desc:"desc1"},{name:"b",desc :"desc2"}] }]
```

I tried this :

```
var secondobj= new Array();
var samplejson = {};
```

I just gave

```
samplejson.name = id;
```

After this I am a bit confused as in how to push values to get the above data structure.

Comment: `var secondobj= new Array();
var samplejson = {};
samplejson.one=arrobj;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a simple as:

```
samplejson[id]=arrobj;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var arrobj = [{
"name" : "a",
"desc" : "desc1"
},{
"name" : "b",
"desc" : "desc2"
}]
var secondobj = []; 
secondobj.push({
one : arrobj
})
console.log(secondobj);
```

Check this [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/vasi_32/1rvz3696/3/) for demo

Answer (score 1):

To make the above structure you can try this:

```
var secondobj= new Array();
var samplejson = {};
samplejson.one = arrobj;
secondobj.push(samplejson);
console.log(secondobj) // this will give [{ "one" : [{ name:"a",desc:"desc1"},{name:"b",desc :"desc2"}] }]
```

Comment: samplejson.one = arrobj; becomes a hardcoded value since the value of "one" is dynamic